# Issues in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have been trying to learn CI and implement a blog content management system following a lightweight tutorial I found online today, but I'm currently experiencing some problems in the view.

Adding new entries "works", but I get the following errors on top of the add_new page:

http://pastebin.com/4UhMTqLj

**CONTROLLER**

```
function new_entry()
{
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library(array('form_validation','session'));

    //set validation rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('entry_name', 'Title', 'required|xss_clean|max_length[200]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('entry_body', 'Body', 'required|xss_clean');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('header', $data);
        $this->load->view('admin/new_entry', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer', $data);
    }
    else
    {
        //if valid
        $name = $this->input->post('entry_name');
        $body = $this->input->post('entry_body');
        $this->articles_model->new_entry($name,$body);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '1 new entry added!');
        redirect('articles/new_entry');
    }
}
```

**VIEW**

```
<h2>Add new entry</h2>
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('message')){echo $this->session->flashdata('message');}?>
<?php echo form_open('articles/new_entry');?>
<p>Title:<br />
<input type="text" name="entry_name" />
</p>
<p>Body:<br />
<textarea name="entry_body" rows="5" cols="50" style="resize:none;"></textarea>
</p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

**MODEL**

```
function new_entry($name,$body)
{
    $data = array(
        'entry_name' => $name,
        'entry_body' => $body
    );
    $this->db->insert('entry',$data);
}
```

What can be the cause?

Edit: I'm using Codeigniter 3.

Answer (score 2):

You must initiate the $data variable before passing in to the views.

eg. 
$data = array();
put it on the new entry class

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with the answer from Cha Hernandez, however, another possibility would be:

To remove the `$data` variable altogether:

```
   $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('admin/new_entry');
    $this->load->view('footer');
```

This is mainly because you're not actually passing any information to the view, so there is no point in having it in the instance.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Change your CONTROLLER TO file below code  where i removed variable $data since it is not assigned to any values and passing undefined variable $data is not necessary.

```
function new_entry()
    {
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library(array('form_validation','session'));

        //set validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('entry_name', 'Title', 'required|xss_clean|max_length[200]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('entry_body', 'Body', 'required|xss_clean');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('admin/new_entry');
            $this->load->view('footer');
        }
        else
        {
            //if valid
            $name = $this->input->post('entry_name');
            $body = $this->input->post('entry_body');
            $this->articles_model->new_entry($name,$body);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '1 new entry added!');
            redirect('articles/new_entry');
        }
    }
```